# Cakephp HABTM with multiple joins needed

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm very new to Cakephp.  I have all my model associations working fine but this one is stumping me and I haven't found anyone who has solved a similar problem.  Here goes..

I have 4 tables:  
**people**

```
+-----+-------------------+
| Id  | first_name        |
+-----+-------------------+
|   1 | jim               | 
|   2 | bob               | 
+-------------------------+
```

**facility_project_people**

```
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
| Id  | facility_project_id | person_id |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
|   1 |          5          |     1     |
|   2 |          6          |     1     |
|   3 |          7          |     2     |
+---------------------------+-----------+
```

**facility_projects**

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Id  | facility_id | project_id|  type_id  |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|   1 |       1     |     1     |     1     |
|   2 |       2     |     3     |     2     |
|   3 |       2     |     5     |     3     |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**projects**

```
+-----+-------------+
| Id  | name        |
+-----+-------------+
|   1 |  Audit      | 
|   2 |  Inventory  | 
|   3 |  Tax        |
|   4 |  Consulting |
+-------------------+
```

So I have people who can be involved in many projects per facility
I'm trying to make a model association to get from Person to the Projects they are involved with.

The MySQL query would be something like:

`SELECT 
    p.first_name,
    pr.name
FROM people p
left join facility_project_people fpp 
    ON p.id = fpp.person_id
left join facility_projects fp 
    ON fpp.facility_project_id = fp.id
left join projects pr
    ON fp.project_id = pr.id`

Using a hasAndBelongsToMany Assocation, I understand how to get as far as the facility_projects table.

```
class Person extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    PersonFacilityProject' => array(
            'className' => 'Project',
            'joinTable' => 'facility_project_people',
            'foreignKey' => 'person_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'facility_project_id',
        ),
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't give me what I need

When viewing a person, I'd like to see related projects, but I'm stumped in how to get to the projects table. I'd like to be able to add another join table and foreign key to the association, but cakephp doesn't seem to allow this.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: How did you try to retrieve the data and what is the result of your try?

Comment: The facility_projects table should be its own model (see [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)). That new model _belongsTo_ Projects (and belongsTo Facility and belongsTo Type). Then you can have Person HABTM facilty_projects, which is already related to your projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state the version of cakephp you were using. However, you can use "contain" to do this (since your models are not all directly related) as shown below:

```
    $conditions = [
        'contain' => [
            'FacilityProjectPerson'=>[
                'FacilityProject'=>[
                    'Project'=>[
                        'fields'=>['Project.name']
                    ],
                ],
            ], 
        ],
    //  'conditions' => [//just in case you need conditions for selecting people
    //      'Person.id' => $this->id, 
    //  ],
        'fields'=>['Person.first_name']
    ];

    $this->Person->find('all',$conditions);
```